# Cropping Image code for android 3.1 is not working

Tags: android

Here is my code for cropping it works fine on 2.2 and 2.3. But it doesn't work for 3.1. Please solve this. Tested on V2.3(HTC Wildfire S) and V3.1(Samsung 10.1) Thanks in advance.

```
package com.androidworks;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MediaStoreTest extends Activity {

protected static final int PHOTO_PICKED = 0;
private static final String TEMP_PHOTO_FILE = "tempPhoto.jpg";
private Button mBtn;
protected ImageView photo;
protected int outputX = 400;
protected int outputY = 600;
protected int aspectX = 1;
protected int aspectY = 1;
protected boolean return_data = false;
protected MediaStoreTest thiz;
protected boolean scale = true;
protected boolean faceDetection = true;
protected boolean circleCrop = false;
private final static String TAG = "MediaStoreTest";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    thiz = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLaunch);
    photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPhoto);

    mBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                File picFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"rawImge.png");
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
               intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(picFile),"image/*");

                intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                intent.putExtra("aspectX", aspectX);
                intent.putExtra("aspectY", aspectY);
                intent.putExtra("outputX", outputX);    
                intent.putExtra("outputY", outputY);
                intent.putExtra("scale", scale);
                intent.putExtra("return-data", return_data);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getTempUri());
                intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
                intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection",!faceDetection); // lol, negative boolean noFaceDetection
                if (circleCrop) {
                    intent.putExtra("circleCrop", true);
                }

                startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_PICKED);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(thiz, R.string.photoPickerNotFoundText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        });

}

private Uri getTempUri() {
    return Uri.fromFile(getTempFile());
}

private File getTempFile() {
    if (isSDCARDMounted()) {

        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),TEMP_PHOTO_FILE);
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Toast.makeText(thiz, R.string.fileIOIssue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return f;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

private boolean isSDCARDMounted(){
    String status = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (status.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        return true;
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case PHOTO_PICKED:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data == null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Null data, but RESULT_OK, from image picker!");
                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_photo_picked,
                                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    t.show();
                    return;
                }

                final Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                if (extras != null) {
                        File tempFile = getTempFile();
                        // new logic to get the photo from a URI
                        if (data.getAction() != null) {
                            processPhotoUpdate(tempFile);
                        }                  
                }
        }
        break;
    }
}

/*
 *  processes a temp photo file from 
 */
private void processPhotoUpdate(File tempFile) {

    Log.w(TAG, "processPhotoUpdate is called");

    FileInputStream fisForResilt = null;
    Bitmap result = null;
    try {
        fisForResilt = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
         result = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fisForResilt);
        fisForResilt.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(result.getWidth(),result.getHeight());
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
    photo.setLayoutParams(params);
    photo.setImageBitmap(result);

}

}
```

My layout looks like this and you need to have a image on your sdcard "rawImage"for this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >
<TextView  
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:text="@string/summary"
 />
 <Button
 android:id="@+id/btnLaunch"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Launch Media Gallery"
 />
 <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imgPhoto"
 android:layout_width="400dip"
 android:layout_height="400dip"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please put more effort into your question. "Doesn't work" is meaningless, please tell exactly what the result is.

Comment: @Tim: After cropping image a progress dialog  for saving picture appears and it hangs up.The progress dialog won't go at all.

Answer (score 0):

The cropping intent is not part of the public API. There is only one solution which is guaranteed to work an all devices: integrate the cropping code into your own app. This is easily possible because the official android gallery app is open source :-)

If you dont want that you can try to find out what the name of the cropping activity on the samsung device is by starting it manually and observing the logcat. It should be something like `com.android.sec.gallery3d.app.CropImage`